# How do I display date values from the database to the report viewer?

Tags: c#, mysql, date, reportviewer

I currently have this code for the filling up of DataSet and DataTables to load it in the Report

```
public void load1()
    {
        string sql = "";
        sql = "select customer,employee,service,price, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') as asd from tbltransaction where CONCAT(customer,employee,service) LIKE '%" + textBox21.Text + "%' order by `date` desc;";
        string constring = "server=localhost;database=dbhorizon;uid=root;password=1234";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring);       
        MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        reportViewer1.Visible = true;
        reportViewer1.Reset();
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
        reportDataSource.Value = ds.Tables[0];
        reportDataSource.Name = "DataSet1";
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);            
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Services_and_Product_List.Report2.rdlc";
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

and this is where I trigger load1() method

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string sql = "";
        if (textBox21.Text == "")
        {
            if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
            {                

                load1();                    
            }
}
```

and this is the construction of the table i am using

```
CREATE TABLE `tbltransaction` (`customer` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`employee` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

the other columns like employee and such, loads perfectly in the report viewer, except for the date part. this is the output

this is the output of the sql code used above that is stored in listview and proven that it is working perfectly

[image: this is the output of the sql code used above that is stored in listview and proven that it is working perfectly]

And this is the output where the dates does not load in the report viewer.
[image: And this is the output where the dates does not load in the report viewer.]

what could be the problem here? i've stayed up for like 28 hrs to figure this out. advance thankyou's for all the answers and i am willing to give more details if needed.

Comment: Can you add a datagridview quickly and see if that displays the date? Also did you set a breakpoint in the debugger to make sure the datable has that column populated? 28 hrs is too long. Try adding 1 datatable and adding a single row to it without connecting to the db and see if that works. Try different things. Try all of the things I mentioned. Start with debugger. Remove the date formatting from the query and just select the column as is and see if that works

Comment: i kinda made it work but yeah somewhat it doesn't follow the format yyyy-MM-dd. oh well all that matter is it worked. thanks for the advice, ill try to fiddle with it more til i get the results i need

Comment: tho the result is like this 11/29/2017 12:00:00.

Comment: is there a way to remove the time?

Comment: i changed the date into a varchar. i was getting tired of dealing with time and dates